# Attaching event handler to each table cell at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a table at design time and adding rows to it at runtime.
I want to attach a mouseover event to each row of first column which displays the respective tooltip.

```
for(ctr=0;ctr<noOfRows;ctr++){
   var myTable=document.getElementById("myTable");
   var newRow = myTable.insertRow(1);

   var cell0 = newRow.insertCell(0);
   cell0.innerHTML="Cell Data"+"<div class='hiddenToolTip' id='tip"+ctr+"'>"+tooltip+"</div>";

   cell0.onmouseover=function(){
        $("#tip"+ctr).show('blind',500);
   };

   cell0.onmouseout=function(){
        $("#tip"+ctr).hide();
   };
}
```

The problem is that the 'ctr' variable is always coming as the highest value inside 'onmouseover' and 'onmouseout' function.

Comment: Where is the `i` coming from within your onmouseover and onmouseout functions? should you not be refencing `ctr`?

Comment: Sorry its not i..but its 'ctr' in the code...The problem still exists.

Comment: Hi buddy i modfied my answer as well as i pasted link check that and you can able to achieve th task you want ...

Comment: are you able to get that or not ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just pass this in function argument and get value of ctrl as below using id of the element

```
cell0.onmouseover=function()
{      
    $(this).children("div[id^='tip'] ").show('blind',500);    
    };
```

Check this example for this : [Javascript: Adding OnMouseOver And OnMouseOut Using DOM](http://triaslama.wordpress.com/2008/02/02/javascript-adding-onmouseover-and-onmouseout-using-dom/)

Comment: Not working. 'this' keyword is not being accepted. 'Syntax Error'

Comment: But I want to know that why ctr was always coming as the highest value. What is the concept behind it ?

Comment: @f because there ctr is local variable and in method you cannot refer this direcly..if you refer in you over event it alwys take last value of it ...in mouse over funtion ctrl variable is not going to change value for each binding ...

Comment: OK.got it.Thanks for the explanation. SOLVED.